# Pygame word wrap

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm working on having text displayed in my pygame I'm creating. I have it drawn with a nice space between the text but with word wrapping the text overlaps just a tad. Here is how I'm wrapping my text.

```
def reOrderChat(nText, nColor):
    ''' Reorders the chat text on screen and creates new lines '''

    # rearrange the lines first so they stay correct.
    for c in range(19, 0, -1):
        DrawnChat[c + 1].text = DrawnChat[c].text
        DrawnChat[c + 1].color = DrawnChat[c].color
        DrawnChat[c + 1].y = DrawnChat[c].y - 8
        #print "Text at " + str(c + 1) + " is " + DrawnChat[c + 1].text

    # check if textlength is greater than the chat list length
    textLength = g.chatFont.size(nText)[0]

    if textLength > 459:
        # todo: allow custom size chat list (459 is found with GIMP)
        # todo: optimize the loop

        lines = ['']

        words = nText.split()
        curLine = 0
        curLineLength = 0

        for i in range(len(words)):
            word = words[i]

            # if adding the new word to the current line would be too long,
            # then put it on a new line
            wordLength = g.chatFont.size(word)[0]

            if (curLineLength + wordLength) > 400: # todo: why does it only work with 400?

                # only move down to a new line if we have text on the current line
                lines.append('')
                curLine += 1
                curLineLength = 0

            lines[curLine] += word + ' '
            curLineLength += wordLength

        curLine +=1

        for line in lines:
            print line
            print str(curLine)
            # here is where it creates new chat lines. This is where the issue is.
            DrawnChat[curLine].text = line
            DrawnChat[curLine].color = nColor
            DrawnChat[curLine].y += 8
            curLine -= 1


    else:
        # text fits, so just print it
        # lastly add the new text and color at position 1
        DrawnChat[1].text = nText
        DrawnChat[1].color = nColor
        DrawnChat[1].y  += 8
```

Here is a screen shot of the text. Between the first two lines there is not enough space. Through the spacing after the first two lines to the MOTD: is just fine. Am I setting the y value wrong when there are multiple lines?

[image: Text to screen issue]

Comment: Is the space to the MOTD actually ok? or does it just look ok because of the blank line before it? Have you tried increasing the y value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to increase the spacing between the lines?

```
DrawnChat[curLine].y += 12
```

If this doesn't work; please check, if the surface have the right height.

If you at any point, think it would be necessary to change the font-size. Please, consider using a variable instead of hard-coded `DrawnChat[curLine].y += 8`.

Comment: Yea I tried to change the spacing. I'll have to double check the surfaces that are being drawn. Lastly I will push it over to a variable instead of hard coding it. Thanks for the tips. I'll get back to let you know how it works out.